# Comprehensible->comprehensibility

Tags: suffixes

In English, why does the word 'comprehensible' when switched to nouns become 'comprehensibility' which is not 'comprehensiblity'?

Answer (score 3):

You will find that to be true for 100s of word pairs, for example Responsible & Responsibility. Such word pairs represent words of French or Latin origin.

**-ible**

> Suffix forming adjectives.
>
> Origin
> From French *-ible* or Latin *-ibilis*

([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/-ible))

**-ibility**

> Forming nouns corresponding to adjectives ending in *-ible* (such as *accessibility* corresponding to *accessible*).
>
> Origin
> From French *-ibilité* or Latin *-ibilitas*

([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/-ibility))

Examples include

Possible, possibility
Legible, legibility
Flexible, flexibility
Visible, visibility
Comprehensible, comprehensibility
Responsible, responsibility
Accessible, accessibility

Comment: Of course, it's exactly the same with ***-able / -ability***. Which works fine for ***suit / suitable / suitability***, but doesn't quite cut the mustard with ***comfort / comfortable / [comfortability?!]***

Comment: Well I can imagine someone using  *comfortability* at some point, if they haven't already. @Fumble

Comment: i really thank you for answer my question! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Clare: At a pinch, so can I (although probably only as a facetious usage). And it would depend on ***comfortable*** being interpreted as meaning ***capable of being comforted*** - which *is* actually listed in the full OED, but it's marked both ***obsolete*** and ***rare***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In my neck of the woods, the problem actually comes up at ***comfort / comfortable***. Around here, *comfortable* generally comes out *comfterble* (I'll actually reword sentences to avoid having to say it). In fact, I'm pretty sure I've heard *comfterbility*, as in "I know my couch is hideous, but you can't beat it for **comfterbility**."

Comment: @1006a: The full OED doesn't include ***comfortability***, irrespective of spelling, pronunciation, or intended meaning. I'm sure for your context most people would just say *You can't beat it for **comfort***, but I do note that OED have a dedicated entry for ***comfortableness*** (for those who like quirkiness for quirkiness's sake! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, people use all sorts of words in conversation that don't show up in the OED; I'm not suggesting it *should* be a word, just that it doesn't pose a problem for folks around me. I doubt most would say "you can't beat it for comfort", though *comfterbleness* might be possible. I'm pretty sure the pronunciation shift has divorced the meaning of *comfort* and *comfortable* to some degree (the former used more for emotional cosseting, the latter for physical).

Comment: @1006a: Google Books claims 24 written instances of [*can't beat it for comfort*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22can%27t+beat+it+for+comfort%22), but I can't find any variants at all based on ***comfortableness, comfortability***, or ***comfterbleness*** (nor would I expect to).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not disagreeing with you at all—I would never use it in print. I'm only talking about *conversational* English, and only in my part of the United States. If you search in the wider web, you'll see that *comfortability* definitely does see use, and is the subject of some debate. I was just speculating that it might seem like a more attractive option to those of us who shift the pronunciation of *comfortable* such that the ending lends itself more easily to a -bility conversion, and less to a shift back to *comfort*.

Comment: @1006a: And I'm not suggesting that nobody ever says ***comfterbleness*** or ***comfterbility*** in conversational contexts. But you wrote *I doubt most would say "you can't beat it for comfort", though comfterbleness might be possible*, and I certainly disagree with *that*. Perhaps there are a few mavericks who could use such oddball forms *deliberately* (without being facetious), but mostly it would just be people whose lips are moving faster than their brains (so they can't abandon the standard ***comftable*** stress pattern quickly enough to switch to ***comfort, comfiness*** in time).

Comment: I actually said *it doesn't pose a problem for folks around me. I doubt most would say "you can't beat it for comfort"* and in both sentences I was talking about *folks around me*. We'll have to agree to disagree if you think I'm wrong about that.